# jQuery Mobile Sliders Image Sequences

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, slider, html5-canvas

I a building a mobile app using jQuery Mobile framework to display medical images on smartphones. I have multiple images (at times 100+) that I want to display on a single canvas and i want to use a slider to navigate through the images as smoothly as possible, as they are part of a series which create an animation.

At the moment I have got this far with the code below but when sliding through the image is not a smooth from on to another and there is a lag. You have to move it at a specific index to display the image, the on to the next one as it does not display it as you slide through the values.

My other option is to place all the images in img tags and hide/show them as you use slide through the array index. But i want to use the canvas as at some point i want to zoom/filter the images.

Any ideas, plugins/libraries would be very helpful.

```
var a=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var a_ctx=a.getContext("2d");

var images = [];

$("#slider").attr("max", instUrlArr.length).slider("refresh");

//on page init it will preload all images from array
for(var i = 0;i<instUrlArr.length;i++){
    images[i] = new Image();
    images[i].src = instUrlArr[i];
}
$('#slider').slider({
        stop: function(event,ui){
        var sliderVal = $('#slider').val();
        var img = images[sliderVal];
        console.log('source ' + img.src);

        a_ctx.drawImage(img,400,300);
    }
});
```

Comment: try this http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/05/27/awesome-mobile-image-gallery-web-app/

Comment: @Omar thanks for the link. I have used PhotoSwipe for the prototype which works well, but I wanted to be able to zoom/add filter effects on the images and use a slider as opposed to buttons. The canvas seemed like optimal choice.

Comment: This one is different than photoswipe, and could be modified easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out by using the change event rather than using the slider start/stop events. When i slide through the images they are drawn smoothly from one to another.

```
$('#slider').change(function(){
    var sliderVal = $(this).val();
    var img = images[sliderVal];
    console.log('source ' + img.src);
    a_ctx.drawImage(img,300,300); 
});
```